# cut letter with package T1 fontenc

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

With the package fontenc and option T1, I sometimes get a letter that is "cut" or "stepped over" by its neighbor.

For instance, with this code :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\textit{definition}

\end{document}
```

I get this result :

[image]

where the f steps over the e.

The thing is that I don't get such a bug using, for example, Overleaf.
I am using TexMaker 5.0.3 for Windows and MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit (up to date, as far as I know).

Comment: Did you install `cm-super`? Other than that, you can load`lmodern`.

Comment: No idea what cm-super is, but lmodern worked fine ! Thanks !

Comment: It is an extension to the default `cm` fonts (Computer Modern) with the T1 encoding.